# PROS and CONS on using one classPageObject for storing all xpath/css selectors and etc., using Java

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

What are the PROS and CONS on using onePageObject class for storing my all xpath/css selectors and etc., and then use them in other page object methods.

I'm thinking how lower the needless xpath's that are constantly is repeating in different pageObjects class.

Any suggestions?

Somebody already doing this? If yes, is it easyer or harder to find what you need?

I'm thinking to use the code something like this:

```
ObjectClass.java
 Public class ObjectClass myXpaths {

   @FindBy(xPath);
   private button xPathButtonAdd;

   @FindBy(xPath);
   private button xPathButtonDelete;

   @FindBy(xPath);
   private button xPathButtonCancel;
 }

ObjectClass2.java
 import ObjectClass;

 Public class void ObjectClass2 myPageObject {

   ObjectClass smth = new ObjectClass();

   smth.xPathButtonAdd.click();
   smth.xPathButtonDelete.click();
   smth.xPathButtonCancel.click();
 }
```

Comment: could you give an example of how you want to organize your selectors and how you want to use them later on?

Comment: @AlvaHenrik lets say that code woul look something like that above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CONS as I see it:

1. One huge class of selectors - huge classes are typical code smell.
2. Other page object class would inherit from or initialize an object
   with a lot of selectors it doesn't need.
3. Violation of [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) (SRP).

PROS:

1. Avoiding some repetitive code - you could avoid it by other means
   (see example bellow)
2. ....

If the reason why you think of doing this is minimizing repetitive code, you should rather think of how to extract that repetitive code to separate classes. For instance, given a application with multiple pages where every page has standart search section, you can extract it to separate class SearchSection or SearchBox and use it in pages where you need it.

If you gave an example of repetitive code or what do you want to do, it would be easier to suggest something.

Comment: Hi, thanks for some thoghts that you shared. What does SRP stand for?

Comment: After some time coding automated tests I noticed that this idea is not bad if you have xpathUtils helper for dublicate xpaths to use one place, but if xpath is used only once in one page, is useless to create one page for all xpaths.

Comment: Sorry for long response, SRP stands for single responsibility pattern :)

Comment: Thank you for explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I get now where you want to go. I would definitely recommend separating the selectors from the actual code. We organize our page objects in classes that more or less represent one screen of the application under test. Those classes are then again in a structure of packages representing the business process that is tested. That way we can easily reuse page elements and if something in the application under test changes we only have to touch this "repository" of page elements but not the script that does the action. We also use prefixes like "link", "button", "input" and so on that indicate the type of page element so that the action code is easier to understand and read.
But I would really advise against throwing all in one huge class, because you might have trouble finding things later on. :-)

Comment: That's a good point, as now how I think about it more in future, I see, that if I will do this, it might be hard to track and change the changes. Thanks for sharing your opinion! :)